# Is machine learning successful in solving combinatorial optimisation problems in NP-hard? Discuss problem of scheduling using machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, research

Chess is Exp-complete. I assume Alpha GO is also Exp complete. Correct me if I am wrong. Now deep reinforcement learning has been successful in tackling this problem. What about other more practical problems like scheduling, bin-packing, and routing? 
In particular, what is the state of the art for scheduling applications using ML techniques? How should one start in this direction?

Comment: Downvoters, could you kindly put the reason as well?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to get to EXP-complete in order to get a hard problem.
NP-Complete is bad enough...

Cryptographic assumptions (e.g., the existence of [one way functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function)) are also a good way to create hard problems

There is research in the area lead of plenty of results like [Cryptographic Limitations on Learning Boolean Formulae and Finite Automata](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~mkearns/papers/crypto.pdf) - [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) is not [PAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probably_approximately_correct_learning) learnable in polynomial time.

However, there is an important difference between these negative results and writing a great chess program.
The negative results means that for a given problem no algorithm will solve ALL instances (let say, in polynomial time).
That doesn't mean that you won't be able to play better the human champion on some/most/all instances.

Note that this complexity observation is indifference of the technique. Machine learning is just another (useful) way to cope with these problems.

As for machine learning ability to cope with these problems, you can find NP-Complete problems all around in machine learning (SVM, Neural Networks, Decision trees). That didn't prevent them from finding many useful models.

Comment: Thanks for the useful insight. I just gave the examples of EXP-complete problems, not saying I would like only EXP-complete problems to be targetted.

Comment: Sure. Let alone that defeating Kasparov *feels* much harder than packing bins ;-)

Comment: Why did you put feels in italics? You do not agree with it?

Comment: I do agree, but that is in the domain of feeling, not math.